# Using Akka.Net Cluster utilities in a single ActorSystem

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I'm trying to create a simulation of a network of multiple nodes to analyse network traffic.
The nodes themselves are going to be implemented using Akka.Net and should be able to use some of Akka.Net cluster capabilities. But the simulation itself is intended to run on a single machine and might possibly contain multiple thousands of these nodes.

Because of the amount of nodes, I'd like to avoid creating a single ActorSystem for each node. Is it possible to still use the cluster module and it's abilities, such as roles, distributed broadcasting, member-up-down-events etc. within a single actor system?

Is it maybe possible to fake remote deploy them and create a fake transport that simply routes all traffic back to the same actor system?

Answer (score 1):

The Multi-Node TestKit in Akka.NET is something that can do this: http://getakka.net/articles/networking/multi-node-test-kit.html

Comment: Is it possible to use the Multi-Node TestKit outside of a test environment? I'm using the Akka within a simulation framework. Also: doesn't it specifically create one ActorSystem per Node? `Launch multiple independent processes each running their own ActorSystem;`